# Cannot get the location - Android

Tags: android

I want to get location in Android 2.2 and I have already added Google gms play services library. And I can set `requestLocationUpdates` and `getLastKnownLocation`, but the location is null.

The log only printed `03-10 01:23:13.720  27437-27437/? V/GPSTracker provider﹕ gps
03-10 01:23:13.720  27437-27437/? V/GPSTracker﹕ requestLocationUpdates
03-10 01:23:13.720  27437-27437/? V/GPSTracker﹕ getLastKnownLocation`. Latitude and longitude didn't show.

```
package com.example.testlocation;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private Context mContext;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    String provider = "";
    float accuracy = 0;

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker() {

    }

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                if (provider != null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,30000,10, this);
                    Log.v("GPSTracker", "requestLocationUpdates");
                }
                if (locationManager != null && provider != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    Log.v("GPSTracker", "getLastKnownLocation");
                    if (location != null) {
                        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Log.v("GPSTracker", latitude+", "+longitude);
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
        getLatitude();
        getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public String getProvider(){
        return provider;
    }

    public float getAccuracy (){
        return accuracy;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView tvLat, tvLong, tvProvider, tvAccuracy;
    private Button btnRefresh;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvProvider = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvProvider);
        tvAccuracy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAccuracy);
        tvLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLat);
        tvLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLong);
        btnRefresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);

        gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        tvProvider.setText("Provider: "+gps.getProvider());
        tvAccuracy.setText("Accuracy: "+gps.getAccuracy());
        tvLat.setText("Latitude: "+latitude);
        tvLong.setText("Longitude: "+longitude);

        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                tvProvider.setText("Provider: "+gps.getProvider());
                tvAccuracy.setText("Accuracy: "+gps.getAccuracy());
                tvLat.setText("Latitude: "+latitude);
                tvLong.setText("Longitude: "+longitude);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testlocation" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".GPSTracker" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Ok, I gotta ask... Have you tested your application properly? Have you moved at least 10 meters AND waited 3 seconds? Then your `onLocationChanged` should have fired and if you logged something in it, it should have been printed... The method `getLastKnownLocation` can return `null` that is completely normal, but your `onLocationChanged` should have fired after you moved 10m and after 3sec, and it should have had new coordinates in it...

Comment: I have a least wait for more than 10 mins, and the latitude and longitude still be 0.

Comment: Did you move 10m while waiting? You need to move and wait for time to pass (As per documentation: "The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting up the location and getting the location right away! This does not give enough time to get the location and therefore you are getting null. What you should do is implement locationlistener and in there  (onLocationChanged method), get and display the location

You put your GPS code in a service and you actually don't have the rest of code for the service, and you didn't even start it. I think you are new to android and you are attempting advanced areas already. So here is my suggestion to you

Instead of

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
```

do

```
public class GPSTracker  implements LocationListener {
```

Also in GPSTracker do the following
public void init() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            if (provider != null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,30000,10, this);
                Log.v("GPSTracker", "requestLocationUpdates");
            }else{
             Log.v("GPSTracker", "ERROR1");
            }

        }else{

       Log.v("GPSTracker", "ERROR2");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public Location getLocation() {

        return location;
    }
```

And in your MainActivity.java, do gps.init() after you instantiate it.. Run it and see if it runs and watch the output for errors.

Also don't forget to remove the service from your xml

Comment: But I have already set onLocationChanged, 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }  
 , and set a button on MainActivity to refresh, but still cannot get location.

Comment: Well then you should've put it in the code above so we can see it!... Is your OnLocationChanged being called? Put a break point or a statement

Comment: Also, can you put a print a statement to see what provider you are getting from "getBestProvider"?

Comment: First thing to do is to see if you are hitting the code in the onlocationchanged. Put a break point or a log statement.  Also print out/log the name of the provider you are getting. This will help see where the problem. My expectation is either you are not getting location updates OR Criteria is returning you empty provider

Comment: Also I would suggest, replace this locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,30000,10, this);  with locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,3000,0, this); and give it a try.

Comment: You are right, the onLocationChanged method never called, so what can I do?

Comment: Did you do what I said in the last comment? Replace the values of the requestLocationUpdate?

Comment: Ohhhh! you declared this as a service and never started it! I will update my answer above

Comment: Yes, even I set to `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0, this);`, it still not working.